# How do I implement an on OnClickListener to start an activity for each position of my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I have no idea which specific method I should implement an `OnClickListener` or how to set up the `OnClickListener` to take the right context and return the right position for each new intent.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String [] name={"One","Two","Three","Four",
            "Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
    "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen"};
    private static final String TAG = "###RecyclerViewAdapter###";
    private String[] mHeaderSet;



    public RecyclerAdapter(final String[] headerSet){
        mHeaderSet = headerSet;

    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);



        }
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final TextView header = (TextView) viewHolder.cardView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        header.setText(mHeaderSet[position]);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHeaderSet.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34719444/2590478